# How to add a sharepoint item using axios with person and hyperlink column

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, azure-functions, webhooks

I'm using azure function to post the items. There's no problem in adding other fields like, single line, number, choice etc.

I'm facing an issue with hyperlink and person column.

Answer (score 0):

- I think below code should work for you.
- For Hyperlink column use below code.

```
{UrlField: {
            "__metadata": { type: "SP.FieldUrlValue" },
            Description: "Description",
            Url: "https://318studios.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/Style%20Library/DSC_0024.JPG?csf=1&e=3729ff5a8af5402f8158192f61964747"
        },
}
```

- Reference
- [Update a list item column of hyperlink type](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/issues/682#issuecomment-355071531)
- For updating people or group use below code.

```
// Person or group, single and multiple
  { FieldName: 'PersonField', FieldValue: JSON.stringify([{ Key: LoginName }]) },
```

- Reference
- [List Items System Update options in SharePoint Online](http://blog.arvosys.com/2018/07/06/list-items-system-update-options-in-sharepoint-online/index.html)